# Django Formset: how to get the current user? (using django-extra-views)

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-users

I'm used to collecting the current logged in user in a CreateView and passing it to the form like so:

```
class MakeFantasyTeam(CreateView):
    form_class = MakeFantasyTeamForm
    [...]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.team_manager = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(MakeFantasyTeam, self).form_valid(form)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when using an InlineFormSetView as provided by [django-extra-views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I get an error **NOT NULL constraint failed: tournament_invite.invited_by_id** and I'm not sure how to get the user.id passed on to the form.

**My View:**

```
class InvitePlayersView(InlineFormSetView):
    template_name = 'invite_players.html'
    model = Tournament
    inline_model = Invite
    form_class = InvitePlayerForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'tourney_id'
    factory_kwargs = {'can_delete': False, 'extra': 1}

    def formset_valid(self, formset):
        tourney_id = self.kwargs['tourney_id']
        formset.instance.invited_for = Tournament.objects.filter(id=tourney_id).get()
        formset.instance.invited_by = self.request.user
        formset.save()
        return super(InvitePlayersView, self).formset_valid(formset)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('make_team', kwargs={'tourney_id': self.object.invited_for.id})
```

**My Model:**

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=320, null=False, blank=False, validators=[EmailValidator],)
    invited_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    invited_for = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**My Form:**

```
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invite
        fields = ('name', 'email',)
```

Any tips or hints much appreciated!

Thank you,

Jon

Edit: Just to clarify what I'm trying to do here; I want a user to submit a formset. The data of that formset should be stored in the model, and the userid of the submitting user should also be stored in the model. I don't seem to be able to pass on the userid though.

Comment: or you logged in when submitting the form? you logic probably seems to be correct except for the fact that it should use a [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to allow only authenticated users to access this view.

Comment: Yes I am logged in - I'll add the login requirement, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly confident self.request.user is still managing to get the logged in user. My issue seems to be getting that value added to the form's data before the form posts its data.

Comment: What do you mean by fairly confident? Please use `breakpoint` or `print` to actually confirm your "confidence".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do here, As per my understanding you want to use the currently logged in user's information. To do so you can append the user's info in the session dictionary. After that you can use the information in templates or in other views too.

## In authentication view

```
def login(request):
    #your necessary data
    request.session['user_id']=The_user_id
    request.session['user_name']=The_userName
```

To access data in the template

```
{% request.session.user_id %}
{% request.session.user_name %}
```

To access data in other views

```
def myview(request):
    user_id= request.session['user_id']
    user_name= request.session['user_name']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback. Basically I'm trying to get the userid as it's a required field in the model that the form posts into.

Comment: You can do one thing. Make a new record (user_id or user_name) in your models where you are saving the form. Just add `null=True` and `blank=True`. In the view which is handling your post request, you can extract the last record after saving the form and modify the `user_id` or `user_name` field OR you can add the user detail in the post request processing procedure too.